# How to insert a string(Fri Nov 19 16:23:54 +0800 2010) into a table field whose type is TIMESTAMP?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using Python and MYSQLdb to connect to Mysql.
and now i need to insert a string "Fri Nov 19 16:23:54 +0800 2010" into a field, how can i do?

Comment: What time zone are you assuming for your TIMESTAMP field?

Comment: the same with the time zone in the string: +0800

Answer (score 1):

You can parse that sting with Python `time.strptime()` method and then convert it to string required by MySQL using `strftime()`. Unfortunately my Python 2.6 cannot handle `%z` directive, but you can check on your implementation that code:

```
import datetime

def test_dt(d, f):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, f)
    print('%s -> %s' % (d, dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')))
    print('-' * 10)

test_dt('Fri Nov 19 16:23:54 2010', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
test_dt('Fri Nov 19 16:23:54 +8000 2010', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
```

If it fails with `%z` then think if you need that time zone, or if you can remove it from string and apply it to `dt` object other way.

It seems that `%z` issue was reported and solved: http://bugs.python.org/issue6641

Comment: thanks for your help, I have successfully inserted it as what you said.